# how to create multiple files with different name using loop in c++?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have to make a program, which gets some information about many students and save that information in different file with different names.

Suppose the program has got all the information about students. now it has to save that information in different files, I am facing problem in changing name

e.g file.open("filename.txt") // This will create only one file in loop

how can file name be changed with every iteration of the loop ?

Comment: What code do you have and where is your problem? This is not a code writing service, nor can we help you by guessing your problem.

Comment: @churill, I have edited the question. plz, read the question once more.

Answer (score 1):

*"how to create multiple files with different name using loop in c++?*"

Use a loop to repeat following steps:

- Create a filename, e.g. by incrementing a number and converting to string
- Open a file with this newly created filename as output file
- Close the file. Now it's written to your filesystem if the parent path exists and the permissions are correct.

Example

```
std::string path = "/path/";
for (short i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::string filename = "student" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
    std::ofstream file(path + filename);
    file << student[i];
} // file.close() not necessary, destructor will close
```

Comment: ThankYou  

could you make it simple

ofstream file[3];

    for (short i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        file[i].open("student1.txt");

        // now, here how to change file name into "student2.txt" and "student3.txt" and so on 
           every iteration of loop
}

Comment: @Nasrullah Changed it. You don't need an array of filestream. You can use one filestream.